# Excel file disappears from Solution Explorer when it is saved

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, solution-explorer

Set-up: Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010 (with TFS2010*), Excel 2007 Full/2010 Starter

Reproduction steps:

1. In an empty Visual Studio, click on File -> New Project -> Blank Solution, note the solution directory and click on OK
2. Open Excel and create a new Excel file, save it in the new Solution directory, then close Excel
3. Right-click on the new Solution in Solution Explorer -> Add -> Existing Item
4. Select the Excel file, and once added to the solution, it should automatically open in Excel (if it doesn't, then open it manually)
5. Save the Excel file
6. The file disappears from Solution Explorer

Does anyone know how to stop this from happening?

> 

** I don't think TFS has anything to do with the situation, but I've added it for completeness

Comment: It appears that this doesn't happen if you add the Excel file to a project, rather than a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO this is a bug in Visual Studio. I have witnessed this many times. Solutions items seem to vanish periodically, and it seems to be triggered by modifying a Solution file outside of VS. Many times I have copied over a file with a newer version, and perhaps because the file is momentarily deleted and then recreated by the copy, VS detects the short-lived deletion and thinks it should be removed from the solution. (By momentarialy I mean perhaps a ms.)

When using TFS, oftentimes when I go to check in something, I'll notice the solution file is checked out, even if I didn't edit it, and when I compare the sln file I realize VS thought a solution file was deleted, so I have to undo the checkout of the sln file. In fact, this has bit me in the butt so many times that now anytime I am checking in the sln file I compare it just to make sure VS didn't try to slip one past me.
(And I've also spent quite a few hours of my life fixing accidental checkins of the sln file by other team members due to this issue.)

Comment: Do you have any idea if this is still an issue in VS2012?